# VBA : FTSearch syntax in lotus notes documents in view

Tags: excel, lotus-notes, vba

Need help with vba code. please have look below on the code.

I want all the document in the view QA\QA Schedule which are in between (1sep2013 - 30sep2013). Here its not the document created date it the date which is taken form the column of the view so that i can pull the data in Excel

'Below is code which i have build what its doing is it is searching all the document and getting me the data which is taking lot of time. If can add a filter on the date we can do it little bit faster but i am not aware of the FT search syntax. how to use it on the view column. please help with this its really urgent.

```
Dim nSess As Object 'NotesSession
Dim sPwd As String
Dim strCnxn As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim db As Object
Dim iviews As Object
Dim IView As Object
Set nSess = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession") 'New:{29131539-2EED-1069-BF5D-        00DD011186B7}
myUsername = ****
myPassword = ****
DSN1 = ("Driver={Lotus NotesSQL Driver (*.nsf)};Server=;Database=;Uid=" & myUsername & ";Pwd=" & myPassword & ";")
Call nSess.Initialize(sPwd)
Set db = nSess.GetDatabase("", "")
Set iviews = db.GetView("QA\QA Schedule")
iviews.AutoUpdate = False 
Set IView = iviews.AllEntries

Set viewparentEntry = IView.Parent

Set viewEntry = viewparentEntry.GetFirstDocument
For i = 1 To IView.Count

Colval = viewEntry.ColumnValues()
For j = 0 To 20
If Colval(0) <> "2013 9" Then
Exit For
ElseIf Colval(18) >= "" Or Colval(18) <= "" Then
Exit For
ElseIf Colval(18) >= "09/01/2013" Or Colval(18) <= "09/30/2013" Then
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(RowCount, colcount).Value = Colval(j)
colcount = colcount + 1
Else
Exit For
End If
Next
j = 0
colcount = 1
RowCount = RowCount + 1
Set viewEntry = viewparentEntry.GetNextDocument(viewEntry)
Next
```

Comment: What is the formula for the view column? If it's just referring to a date-time field that's stored in the documents, then you should be able to do use the FTSearch syntax. If not, then it might be tricky.

Comment: I am not aware how to use FTsearch syntax in VBA.
Exec_date is the columns present in the view. so how can i use the the FTsearch syntax here..

Comment: You can use the FTSearch method of the NotesDatabase class.  You can find documentation here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_FTSEARCH_METHOD_DB.html

Comment: You can also use the FTSearch method of the NotesView class, as shown in Ken's answer. That will be more efficient in cases where there are a large number of documents in the database, but only a portion of them are in the view.

Comment: I am able to get the expected result.
Just one more Road block in my development.

i.e. Suppose if i have the column name or here what we say is FIELD name in FTSearch query syntax as AQAExecDate which the understood by the query that we need to search from the field AQAExecDate.
For which the below query is working fine.

strSearchKeyIssue = "FIELD AQAExecDate >= " & StartDate & " AND FIELD AQAExecDate >= " & EndDate

The problem arise when we have a field(I am taking the column name from the column list where ItemName = "$49") name starting with "$49".

Comment: Am i referring to a correct field. From where can I get the correct field name. If $49 is correct field name then whats the syntax for the same.

Comment: $49 is likely the programmatic name of a different column, not an actual field. Programmatic names are created automatically when new columns are created. The default naming scheme is $ + the column number, so this is likely referring to the 49th column in the view. Find that column, verify that the programmatic name is $49 by looking at the column properties dialog, and check the formula for that column. If it is referring to a field, then use the name of that field.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

- You could copy this view or change this view to only show documents between a certain date range, if appropriate.
- You could call the FTSearch method on the database view.  [Some info on syntax for full text searches is here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.notes85.help.doc/sch_refine_query_r.html?resultof=%22query%22%20%22queri%22%20%22syntax%22%20).

Here's an example that gets you a doc collection returned from a full text search on a view:

```
Dim db As Object
Dim iviews As Object
Dim IView As Object
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Set nSess = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession") 'New:{29131539-2EED-1069-BF5D-        00DD011186B7}
myUsername = ****
myPassword = ****
DSN1 = ("Driver={Lotus NotesSQL Driver (*.nsf)};Server=;Database=;Uid=" & myUsername & ";Pwd=" & myPassword & ";")
Call nSess.Initialize(sPwd)
Set db = nSess.GetDatabase("", "")
Set iviews = db.GetView("QA\QA Schedule")
iviews.AutoUpdate = False 
iviews.FTSearch("[SomeDate] >= 9/1/2013 And [SomeDate] <= 9/30/2013")

Set doc = iviews.GetFirstDocument
While Not (doc Is Nothing)
    // Do something here for each document

    Set doc = iviews.GetNextDocument(doc)
Wend
```

Comment: NotesView.FTSearch returns the number of documents found, not a collection. Instead of dc.GetFirstDocument you have to use iviews.GetFirstDocument. Secondly, field names have to be enclosed in brackets, like [SomeDate]. Thirdly, the database must be Full-Text search enabled. And finally, if you rarely need the query (say only once per day), and it's a background agent, you can better use the standard Search method.

Comment: Thanks Burger,

But if you can help in giving me a proper syntax for VBA that would be really help full for me. Also i want to know the below sequence is proper or not.In my view SomeDate  = AQAEXECDATE
    


    Set iviews = db.GetView("QA\QA Schedule")
    iviews.AutoUpdate = False 
    Set dc = iviews.FTSearch("SomeDate >= 9/1/2013 And SomeDate <=  9/30/2013")

Comment: Thanks D.Bugger.  I've updated my answer to fix the use of the FTSearch method.  I also noticed my link was invalid, so I fixed that as well.  @MoshinHilalKondkari, take a look now and see if that answers your question about sequence.  You first need to call FTSearch to filter the view, then you iterate over all the documents in the view within the while/wend block.  Just replace the word "SomeDate" with whatever your field name is.

Comment: Thanks All for your help i was able create the macro successfully. and its working fine.
Just one enhancement i wanted in the macro that its taking almost 5-10 mins to get the data in the excel sheet is there any way I can reduce the timing if possible. 5-10 mins are fine with me but then too if it can we reduce to 2-3 mins then it would be great.

Comment: Thanks All for your help i was able create the macro successfully. and its working fine. Just one enhancement i wanted in the macro that its taking almost 5-10 mins to get the data in the excel sheet is there any way I can reduce the timing if possible. 5-10 mins are fine with me but then too if it can we reduce to 2-3 mins then it would be great.

Comment: I'm sure folks can help, but it would be best to open a new question, show your code, and ask about how to improve performance.  Thanks!